# Adding a database image as a background in css in Django

Tags: html, css, django

In Django, I want to add an image from the database as a background image.

Showing it just as an image, the code looks like:

```
{% for image in  this_collection.collectionimage_set.all %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <img src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image }}'/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to be able to find the first image in each collection and display it as a background, instead of just an image. Is this possible? How do I do this in the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="background:url('{ this_collection.collectionimage_set.all.0.url }') 50% 50% no-repeat"></div>
```

Comment: Not quite there, but led me in the right direction. What worked was: style="background: url('{{ this_collection.collectionimage_set.all.0.image.url }}') 50% 50% no-repeat;"

Answer (score 0):

I've marked vadimchin's answer as correct, because it was mostly there. What worked was:

style="background: url('{{ this_collection.collectionimage_set.all.0.image.url }}') 50% 50% no-repeat;"

Note:
- double {{}}
- image.url at the end